# Number of Objects Resulting from a Loose xaml File

Tags: wpf

Suppose I have a loose xaml file with one resource in it, keyed "MyResource", and that I pull that loose xaml file into two other xaml files via ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries. Now suppose I put the following line of code in both of the code-behind files for the two xaml files:

```
object obj = FindResource("MyResource");
```

Will both references be to the same object, or will they be to distinct objects?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: i bet it is one Collection with multiple objects

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how you load the loose XAML file. If you load it once and the same reference is added to two different MergedDictionaries, then by default you'd get the same reference to your "MyResource".

If you load the XAML file twice, you will effectively create two instances of the ResourceDictionary (and thus two instances of your resource).

In a single ResourceDictionary, you can specify if a resource is shared using the [x:Shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx) attribute, which is true by default. Setting this to false, will force new instances to be created for each request of the resource. There are some restrictions on the use of this attribute, which are explained on the MSDN page.